# Search for email by language in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

About 10 years ago, Gmail offered a way to search for email by language with the `lang` operator. Sadly, this doesn't appear to be the case any longer. However, Gmail offers to translate any messages it thinks isn't in your default language. Is there a way to incorporate this into Gmail search / filter?